# Question about /etc/default/grub

Tags: grub2, brightness, overheating

I had previously changed the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"` in order to change my screen brightness with the keyboard buttons.

Now I want to use [THERMALD and Intel P-STATE](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/prevent-your-laptop-from-overheating.html) to prevent my laptop from overheating. But this too suggests a change of the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line in the /etc/default/grub.

Is there any way to have both `acpi_backlight=vendor` and `intel_pstate=enable`?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can simply edit that line this way:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor intel_pstate=enable"
```

And run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Thanks! I was scared to change it as I read that if I do some mistake, my system won't boot.